# In our Flutter app, all the textfields break after pushing a specific widget to the navigator. Any ideas on the reason?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield

We have an flutter app where all textfields used to work fine, properly resizing the view to avoid hiding the textfield under the keyboard.

Now, for some reason we can not yet understand, whenever a specific view(StatefulWidget) is pushed onto the navigator all the textfields on the app suddenly stop working. They all start to have the bug where the keyboards open and automatically close.

I have tried the usual fixes with static keys but doesn't fix the problem and doesn't seem to be the issue, as they work fine before pushing the problematic view.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer to the issue. The culprit seemed to be a `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`. This does seem to bring another issue to attention.

The view in question is a kind of authentication view and after the user properly identifies himself the view should be removed to the widget tree. But somehow the view's build method keeps getting called after the it's replaced with the following method:

```
await Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    SkeletonScreen.routeName,
    (route) => route.isFirst,
);
```

Any tips on why the view is not being disposed and keeps getting the build method called? Should I make a new question to address this specific issue?